# How to deal with a supervisor who doesn't care research and students?

Tags: phd, research-process, thesis, advisor

I'm in the social science discipline. This is the fourth year of my PhD. I'm in the process of writing up my dissertation. However, my supervisor is very lay back. He doesn't care much about my research. On average, it took 2 weeks for me to receive his feedback, but, sometimes, his feedback was not constructive. He often forgot what he said before and contradicted himself. I am very emotionally stressed. I hope to defend my thesis successfully and soon, but I don't see that happening. Any idea about how should I deal with him?

Comment: Have you been working with him for four years or just recently? Is he extremely busy? Does he treat you well other than your research? All would be important to know.

Comment: Thank you! I worked with him for 3 years already. I don't think he is busy, he just doesn't do much work. He is a very kind and nice person; he would try to be supportive, but he rarely fulfills his promises. He is also not very productive compare to his early academic years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, let's guess, an older professor, winding down from research and looking toward retirement. He likes you, but doesn't provide much of any help.

This isn't an impossible situation, unlike many others reported here. In fact, if his reputation, based on past work is good, you may be able to escape successfully and start your own career.

The essential things you need from an advisor is the willingness to sign of on your work so that you get a degree and the willingness to write you good recommendation letters for your first job at least. Anything more than that is helpful and, for some students more of a requirement than others.

It is possible to lean too heavily on an advisor for ideas and direction. Some students need that. But others can work on their own, or even find outside direction to bounce ideas off of and get some feedback. If you are self directed, or can force yourself to be self directed until you finish you can still wind up successful.

It would be a problem if he severely criticizes your work or says it has little value, but it is sort of common to be a bit uninvolved at the end of a career. Some of us are even a bit looney. But, if you can find a way to carry on and the "essentials" are in place then I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Keep him involved to the extent he is willing. Mine his knowledge as much as you can, especially for contacts elsewhere who work in the same field. He may be able to help you build a network, even if he isn't a lot of help on your research problem.

Comment: I would add a bit to this answer about using your whole committee for feedback, particularly in the socia sciences.

Comment: @Dawn, agree. Good catch.